# DSUM function in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to convert an old Microsoft Access report into Crystal reports. I have everything working perfectly except for this last small detail. The Access report uses a DSUM function within an if statement for one of the fields on the report.

After much searching, I've determined that CR doesn't have anything similar.

Here's basically what I'm dealing with.

I have a proposal report. In the details of the report I print the qty, description, and a couple of price fields.

The data looks like something this:

Proposalnum  Partitem  RolltoItem Unitprice

18611.............1..........  NULL........0.00

18611.............2.........  NULL.......17225.92

18611............3............  2............156.90

18611............4.............  2............482.05

What I need to do is when I print a specific part, I need to query through the rest of the records to find the parts that have a matching number in the rolltoitem field and add the unitprice to the part I'm printing.

So in this example when I print partitem #2, I need to add the 156.90 and the 482.05 from parts 3 and 4 to the 17225.92 so I print a total of 17864.87.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there is no such function.

But I would try this.

The general idea is: group the data by ProposalNum and use a subreport to select the "children rows" and sum the "children prices".

Details:

1. Create an empty group section by PartItem.
2. If you want to show only items where RoolToItem is null, use a suppress function for this case.
3. In the details section, put a subreport. The data source of the subreport would be the same of the main report.
4. Change subreport links to select data in subreport based on fields: PartItem in the main report =  RolltoItem in the subreport.
5. Pass other fields to the subreport without select data: ProposalNum, PartItem, UnitPrice. I think you need to create parameters in the subreports before doing that - example: ParentProposalNum, ParentPartItem, ParentUnitPrice.
6. Create a new formula: ParentUnitPrice + Sum ({YourDataSource.UnitPrice})
7. Put the formula in the subreport footer a long with the other fields. Maybe: ParentProposalNum, ParentPartItem, formula.

It is a theoretical solution. I hope it points out to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sum the Unitprice column for all items that have the same value in Rolltoitem, you could do this with a SQL Expression Field.  The code would look something like this.  My Where clause may need tweaked though since I'm not sure what your database structure looks like.

```
(
Select Sum("YourDataBaseTableName"."Unitprice")
From YourDataBaseTableName
Where "YourDataBaseTableName"."Rolltoitem" = *currentRolltoitemValue*
)
```

Syntax can also vary for SQL Expression Fields based upon what type of database you are using.  The syntax I provided is fairly general, but should work on SQL Server.

EDIT:  Adding example with explanation of how it works.

Here is one of my SQL Expression Fields from a crystal report that prints a Bill of Lading for shipped goods.

```
(   
Select  Sum("SHIPMENTS"."PALLET_COUNT")
From    SHIPMENTS
Where   "SHIPMENTS"."BOL_ID" = "BOL"."ID"
)
```

In my database the BOL table is the starting point.  A single BOL can contain 1 or more SHIPMENTS, and a single SHIPMENTS can contain one or more PRODUCTS.
Top level grouping is on BOL.ID.  The PALLET_COUNT is found once and only once on each SHIPMENTS.  I also had a sorting requirement for the data in the details section that prevented me from using a Running Total Field.

This allows a BOL with 2 SHIPMENTS that contains a total of 3 products to look like this:

```
BOL.ID    SHIPMENTS.ID    SHIPMENTS.BOL_ID    PALLET_COUNT    PRODUCT.ID
1         10              1                   2               XXX
1         9               1                   1               YYY
1         10              1                   2               ZZZ
```

The correct PALLET_COUNT for this BOL should be 3, since PRODUCTS XXX and ZZZ are in the same SHIPMENTS and the PALLET_COUNT is duplicated because of its relationship to the PRODUCTS.

Comment: That only works if the *currentRolltoitemValue* is a constant. Like if I hardcode in a 2, it works great. But I need to input the rolltoitem number from the current record I'm printing. I don't know if there's a way to do that.

Comment: See if my edit above helps any with understand how to get the current value.  I feel like i'm not explaining it entirely well though.  Its one of those things that makes perfect sense in my head, but becomes rather complex when I try to explain it.  I apologize for not being able to express my thoughts more clearly.